# Enable JavaScript in PhantomJS with C#

Tags: javascript, c#, phantomjs

I've used PhantomJS in an C# application and it's not executing JavaScript even though the property PhantomJSDriver.Capabilities.IsJavaScriptEnabled is true. The simple page below still executes the content of the *noscript* tag. How can I make PhantomJS execute JavaScript?

I've added Selenium and PhantomJS to my VS2012 solution via NuGet:

```
PM> Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver 
PM> Install-Package PhantomJS
```

I've created a simple HTML page to demonstrate that JavaScript is not enabled:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="javascript:GoToAnotherPage()">Go to another page</a>
    <noscript>
      No JavaScript!
    </noscript>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've used the *PhantomJSDriver*. *src* displays "No Javascript!"

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var phantomDriver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        phantomDriver.Url = @"C:\page.html";
        var src = phantomDriver.PageSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to get what you actually want, but [PageSource](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver_PageSource.htm) is defined as "Gets the source of the page last loaded by the browser."  So of course it includes everything in your HTML file.

Comment: Edited the question. There is a link in the body section which sends you to another page upon clicking. The page source does not change after. I thought that this was an JS issue.. I'new to Phantom.

Comment: I've used phantomDriver.GetScreenshot(); and it's blank. So it's not a JS problem after all.. Thanks. If you write it in an answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PageSource](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver_PageSource.htm) is not supposed to execute JavaScript, it gets the source of the page last loaded by the browser, so it includes everything in your HTML file.

To see the actual state of the page use

```
phantomDriver.GetScreenshot();
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is by default enabled when using PhantomJS. In fact I'm not aware that any WebDriver starts their browser without JavaScript by default.

To make sure that JavaScript is enabled, you can check

```
var phantomDriver = new PhantomJSDriver();
var enabled = phantomDriver.Capabilities.IsJavaScriptEnabled;
```

You can also check experimentally that the JavaScript is running by taking a screenshot and checking that the noscript block is actually not shown. So when the screenshot (`phantomDriver.GetScreenshot();`) is blank in your case then it works.

It is by the way a bad idea to disable JavaScript for the PhantomJSDriver, because many operations of the WebDriver protocol are implemented in JavaScript. Disabling JS would effectively disable the driver.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Even though you weren't first to offer the solution I've accepted yours because the other was only in comment.